# Trying to accomplish something simple with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to use the users entered value into the input being affected by autocomplete's widget, hope the following is self-explanatory of what I want to achieve:

```
source: $(this).val()
```

I think `$(this).val()` won't work because source expects an object?

I'm new to JavaScript, thanks.

```
$(".myinput").autocomplete({
    source:$(this).val()
});
```

Comment: That all depends on exactly what object `$(this)` represents in this snippet.

Comment: could you add more context to what your problem is.  What is "source" part of?

Comment: `"hope the following is self-explanatory"`... It's not :) Please add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the `source` argument incorrectly for jQuery UI's autocomplete.  `$(this).val()` will get the current value out of the `$(this)` DOM object (assuming that's what it's pointing to).

Instead the `source` argument is supposed to be pointing to a source of possible completions for the input.  As an example [from the jQuery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC",
        "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang"];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

As you can see from this example, `source` points to an array of possible tag values that will be autocompleted when the user starts typing.

**To address my new understanding of the OP's question:**

To add the user's current entry into the autocomplete, you could use code like the following:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete("option","source",
    availableTags.concat($("#tags").val()));
```

This would need to be called every time the input changes (using the `keypress` event might be helpful for this.)

Comment: But how to return an array as the source with the user's input value? I have seen this on facebook - on the location fields , they show you " just use "user's value" " - they are retrieving from a remote source plus adding to the autocomplete that they use the input's value, I want to do exactly that. Due to the speed of the response I don't think it's on the remote response the user's input value, but rather it is being grabbed and used in the source, then the remote response with the result set is being prepended to the user's value which I want to use as on option.